# Bullet physics with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, bulletphysics

I have got some problem implementing bullet physics into my opengl game. The thing is that it doesn't want to update my translatef value continously but only at the end.
The code for bullet looks like this:

```
void CGL::initPhysics( void ) {
broadphase = new btDbvtBroadphase();
collisionConfiguration = new btDefaultCollisionConfiguration();
dispatcher = new btCollisionDispatcher(collisionConfiguration);
solver = new btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver;
dynamicsWorld = new btDiscreteDynamicsWorld(dispatcher,broadphase,solver,collisionConfiguration);

dynamicsWorld->setGravity(btVector3(0,-10,0));


ballShape = new btSphereShape(1);
pinShape = new btCylinderShape(btVector3(1,1,1));
pinShape->setMargin(0.04);

fallMotionState = new btDefaultMotionState(btTransform(btQuaternion(0,0,0,1),btVector3(0,10,0)));
btScalar mass = 1;
btVector3 fallInertia(0,0,0);
ballShape->calculateLocalInertia(mass,fallInertia);

btCollisionShape* groundShape = new btStaticPlaneShape(btVector3(0,1,0),1);

btDefaultMotionState* groundMotionState = new btDefaultMotionState(btTransform(btQuaternion(0,0,0,1),btVector3(0,-1,0)));
btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo groundRigidBodyCI(0,groundMotionState,groundShape,btVector3(0,0,0));
btRigidBody* groundRigidBody = new btRigidBody(groundRigidBodyCI);
dynamicsWorld->addRigidBody(groundRigidBody);

btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo fallRigidBodyCI(mass,fallMotionState,ballShape,fallInertia);
btRigidBody* fallRigidBody = new btRigidBody(fallRigidBodyCI);
dynamicsWorld->addRigidBody(fallRigidBody);

for (int i=0 ; i<300 ; i++) {
    dynamicsWorld->stepSimulation(1/60.f,10);

    btTransform trans;
    fallRigidBody->getMotionState()->getWorldTransform(trans);

    fallY = trans.getOrigin().getY();
}
state_list.remove( STATE_FALL_BALL );
printf("stoped\n");
```

}

And the drawing function which is called at the beginning looks like this:

```
void CGL::fallingBall( void ) {
glPushMatrix();

float colBall2[4] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
glMaterialfv( GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, colBall2);

glTranslatef(0.0f,fallY,0.0f);

printf("fallY: %f\n",fallY);

glutSolidSphere(1.0f,20,20);

glPopMatrix();
```

}

The thing is that it shows correct value in this function's printf but translation is called only at the beginning I mean I can only see the last state.

**EDIT**

This is changed function and loop. Gathering all the info I supose it should now work but it doesn't. It doesn't draw anything.

```
initPhysics(){
    for (int i=0 ; i<500 ; i++) 
    {
        draw();

    }
    state_list.remove( STATE_FALL_BALL );
    printf("stoped\n");
}

void CGL::draw(void)
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            current_time = getTime();
            since_update = current_time - last_update;
            printf("time: %f\n",since_update);
            if(since_update>timestep)
            {
                dynamicsWorld->stepSimulation(timestep,10);
                last_update = current_time;
            }
            btTransform trans;
            fallRigidBody->getMotionState()->getWorldTransform(trans);

            fallY = trans.getOrigin().getY();
            fallingBall();
            printf("fallY: %f\n",fallY);
glFlush();
    }
```

And beginning variable declaratins look like that:

```
last_update = 0;
timestep = 100;
current_time = 0;
since_update = 0;
```

Comment: It's nothing to do with opengl, it's to do with for loops. You run your loop 300 times but your don't ever tell it to redraw the bullet?

Comment: @deanWombourne the fallingBall() function is running all the time so it should at least draw 300 balls next to each other. But it doesn't.

Comment: Is it 'running all the time' on the same thread? If you aren't doing your calculations on a background thread then it will wait until the loop is finished before being given a chance to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks a little disorganized. I guess the basic mistake to remedy the immediate problem without delving into multithreading would be to do something like this:

```
//pseudo-code to get the idea
void draw(){
    // clear Buffers and setup matricies
    ....
    //calculate the time that has pased since the last time that the physics have been calculated
    time_t current_time = getCurrentTime();
    time_t since_update = current_time - last_update;

    //if enough time has passed since the last redraw calculate physics
    if(since_update>timestep)
    {
        dynamicsWorld->stepSimulation(timestep,10);
        last_update = current_time;
    }
    btTransform trans;
    fallRigidBody->getMotionState()->getWorldTransform(trans);

    fallY = trans.getOrigin().getY();

    //draw various object
    ....
    fallingBall();
    //swap buffers or flush()
    glSwapBuffers();
}
```

Unless there is a distinct reason for using OpenGL directly I'd suggest that you use a higher level toolkit. Also the usual disclaimer that you are currently using an old version of OpenGL.

Comment: The project is developed in OpenGL so I have to use it. It looks fine, but I have one question - this drwa function is used or implemented inside this for loop or where?

Comment: yes, unless you use a separate thread to calculate the physics, you should check every frame (inside you draw loop) if you should advance the physics and advance them if enough time has passed.

Comment: @sebap123 I think you have some fundamental misunderstanding of what draw-loops are and how to use them? Where do you use `glClear(...)` and `glFlush()` or `glSwapBuffers()` and did you call them before you tried integrating physics?

Comment: Mayby I don't get the whole concept of draw-loops but I have never used them. The glClear(...) and glFlush are in draw function. I forgot to paste them. Now they are in code.

Comment: @sebap123 do you use glut with your application or how did you call your drawing code prior to integrating physics? Also could you clarify `the fallingBall() function is running all the time`?

Comment: yes I am using glut with my application. I want to get everything simple so I have got my collision object and it's position is passed through fallY to fallingBall() function and then to translatef. This same method is working fine with 'my physics' which gets time and move object depending on timer. Now I have inserted fallingBall() function into loop but earlier function was in function which is running all the time so info on console were alternately generated by both of them. I have just no idea what is wrong. On console everything looks fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6473/discussion-between-petert-and-sebap123)